How to calculate a correction for a function
For some reason I'm struggling with understanding conceptually the very last step.
I have a plot of values y(x). I know they're supposed to lie along y=x line but they resemble y=a*log(x)+b better.
I found a the fit for the log function and found "a" and "b" parameters.
Now what I want is to apply this correction to the x values called x_corr, such that they lie closer to the y=x line. Am I supposed to just do this:
x_corr = a*log(x)+b?
If I do it this way all the x values above some value related to y get cut off completely.


